# How to scrape a Facebook page posts using jsoup?

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to scrape in Spring boot with the Jsoup library. I have an empty json as a result of the method, I'm out of ideas.

```
@GetMapping("/test-json")
public String scrapeFacebookPageJson() throws IOException {
    try {
        String facebookPageUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/abcd"; // your URL 

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(facebookPageUrl).get();
        Elements posts = doc.select(".post"); // 

        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Element post : posts) {
            results.add(post.text());
        }

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(results);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // ou logue a exceção
        return "Erro ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea was to look for elements with class `post` and fetch their text content. Seems reasonable enough at first sight.

Take a look at a sample Facebook page in the DOM explorer using DevTools (F12). All elements inside `body` have obfuscated class names (e.g. `x78zum5`). So your strategy of querying elements that contain `post` class won't work.

Not to mention that when you first load the page, you only load the bare bones HTML with a GDPR cookies consent dialog. It doesn't contain much Facebook page content since that is loaded subsequently using JavaScript. You'd have to look into *dynamic web page scraping*, which is something that jsoup can't do.

If you want to programmatically obtain posts from a FB page, I think your best bet is their GraphQL API. This documentation page in particular might be of interest to you: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v19.0/page/feed